# Remove string *by* in MastersDoctoralThesis template

Tags: templates

I am trying to figure out how to remove a word ('by') that seems to appear on the compiled .tex file but which cannot be located anywhere in the document class. Any help is much appreciated.

I am using the MastersDoctoralthesis template as reference to edit my report.[image]

Comment: Just a guess (hence not an official answer), but have you provided an author? Add a line `\author{your name here}` to the preamble and see if that is added to the document.

Comment: Yes now that I add the command in the preamble it is reflected in the abstract. How do I get rid of 'by' ?

Comment: I got the problem fixed. Instead of using \begin{abstract} to define the abstract I used simple commands to include the title 'abstract' with unique formatting.

Comment: Even though that specific template is fairly well known, you can't really assume that people know about all the different templates floating around, so please add a link at the very least, if a complete code example becomes too complicated.

Comment: Why do you assume this is an error? This is by design, this is how the template defines the abstract to look like.

Answer (score 1):

This is a crosspost to [LaTeX-community](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=26936). Quoting my answer from there:

> ```
> \renewcaptionname{english}{\byname}{}
> ```
>
> If you don't want the predefined abstract-environment, why are you using it?